# Reference describing long fiber sequence of classifying spaces from a short exact sequence of topological Abelian groups

Tags: algebraic-topology, reference-request, classifying-spaces

[This](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/integral+Stiefel-Whitney+class#definition) nLab page uses the fact that from a short exact sequence
$$
0\rightarrow K \rightarrow L \rightarrow M \rightarrow 0
$$
of (topological, possibly discrete) Abelian groups, we get a long homotopy fiber sequence
$$
\cdots B^{j-1}M \rightarrow B^j K \rightarrow B^j L \rightarrow B^j M
\rightarrow B^{j+1}K \rightarrow \cdots
$$
of iterated classifying spaces. (Here we use the fact that the classifying space of a topological Abelian group should give another.)

Could anyone suggest a reference that describes the details of the construction of the above long sequence?

Comment: How does $BK$ become a topological group? For example, what is the group structure on $B(\mathbb Z/2)=\mathbb{RP}^\infty$?

Comment: @KentaS if $G$ is an abelian topological group then group multiplication $G \times G \rightarrow G$ is a homomorphism and induces $BG \times BG = B(G \times G) \rightarrow BG$

Comment: I'm just thinking out loud here. If $K \rightarrow L \rightarrow M$ is a fiber sequence then we can define a map $f: \Omega M \rightarrow K$ by lifting a loop $p: I \rightarrow M$ to some path $p': I \rightarrow L$ (taking $0 \in I$ to $0 \in L$) and setting $f(p) = p'(1)$.

This $p'$ can also be chosen continuously w.r.t $p$ and the resulting map $f$ also respects products so induces a map $M = B \Omega M \rightarrow BK$. I don't know how to prove that the fiber of this map is $L \rightarrow M$ though, if you manage to do this though just continue this construction to get the long sequence.